# How to setup Sentry in an Expo built with EAS?

Tags: react-native, expo, sentry

I'm using `sentry-expo` in my Expo app. I'm using EAS builds. All the events are captured successfully in development, but when I make a build, Sentry won't capture any events from the standalone app.

I can see the sourcemaps are uploaded successfully.

In my `App.tsx`:

```js
Sentry.init({
  dsn: Constants.manifest.extra!.sentryDsn || SENTRY_DSN,
  enableInExpoDevelopment: true,
  debug: true,
});
```

My `app.config.js`:

```js
import { SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN, SENTRY_DSN } from "react-native-dotenv";

export default ({ config }) => {
  const extra = {
    sentryDsn: SENTRY_DSN,
  };

  const sentryConfig = {
    file: "sentry-expo/upload-sourcemaps",
    config: {
      organization: "***",
      project: "***",
      authToken: SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN,
    },
  };

  config.hooks.postPublish.push(sentryConfig);

  return {
    ...config,
    extra,
  };
};
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Sir, really i have no clue. But i can imagine, you have to check step 3 in https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-sentry/ and check your sentryConfig.

Its a little bit different

```
{
  "expo": {
    // ... your existing configuration
    "hooks": {
      "postPublish": [
        {
          "file": "sentry-expo/upload-sourcemaps",
          "config": {
            "organization": "your sentry organization's short name here",
            "project": "your sentry project's name here",
            "authToken": "your auth token here"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as mine. I'm adding it dynamically to `app.json`, because I'm using an `.env` file.

Comment: there is no need to pass expo settings? i can remember there was some need for the build process in the docs

Comment: What expo settings you're talking about?

Comment: "expo": {
    // ... your existing configuration

Comment: That's `app.json`. As I said, I'm dynamically updating it through `app.config.js`.

Answer (score 0):

EAS build will write the frames using a format like :

> app:///bundle-{SOME_GUID}.jsbundle

and upload the sourcemaps with names like :

> ~/main.jsbundle

The issue is that the source map name and frames do not match.

You can rewrite these frames during init like this :

```
import { RewriteFrames } from "@sentry/integrations";

  Sentry.init({
    dsn: SENTRY_KEY,
    integrations: [
      new RewriteFrames({
        iteratee: frame => {
          if (frame.filename) {
            // the values depend on what names you give the bundle files you are uploading to Sentry
            frame.filename =
              Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'app:///index.android.bundle' : 'app:///main.jsbundle';
          }
          return frame;
        },
      }),
    ],
  });
```

Then your sourcemaps should be linked correctly on future builds.

Comment: I actually resolved the issue by upgrading to the lastest version of expo SDK. So, this probably is not needed anymore.

Comment: @ataravati if your problem is solved, please select an answer (or write your own) and mark it as the solution

Answer (score 0):

Is your env working fine, as i can see some issues here, first you are using `Constants.manifest` to access the env variables. `Constants.manifest` gets undefined once you post an update to eas. So use `Constants.expoConfig`,

second thing is did you checked whether `react-native-dotenv` is working with the eas or not, as we can directly use `dotenv` to set the env.

install dotenv;

`npm install dotenv` or `yarn add dotenv`

app.config.js;

```
import 'dotenv/config'

expo {
   ...,
   extra: {
      DSN: process.env.DSN // this will be read from .env file locally and for eas build, it will use the env variables add to eas project
}

}
```